# Finding the quaternion which projects one vector onto another

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, quaternions

I'm currently working on a program that requires specifying a quaternion rotation to point a cylinder in the direction of its velocity vector, i.e. projecting the $z$-axis onto that velocity vector. Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/quaternion-for-an-object-that-to-point-in-a-direction), I attempted the following, where $v$ is the velocity vector:

1. Take $\mathbf{v} = (0,0,1)$ and $\mathbf{w}=\frac{v}{\|v\|}$.
2. Determine the axis $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w}$ and $\theta = \arccos(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w})$
3. Convert to a quaternion in the usual way, i.e. $\mathbf{q} = (\cos(\theta/2),\mathbf{a}\sin(\theta/2))$

This, however, produced rotated cylinders which are *slightly* off from the lines they follow (except if the velocity vector is the x or y-axis, in which case it works perfectly). I know it is an issue with the method and not my code, as I've been able to reproduce the issue in Mathematica:

```
vel = {0.00113606,0.01807943,0.02356922};
z ={0,0,1};
axis = Cross[Normalize@z,Normalize@vel];
theta = ArcCos[(Normalize@z).(Normalize@vel)];
c = Cos[theta/2];
s = Sin[theta/2];
q = Normalize@{c, axis[[1]]*s, axis[[2]]*s, axis[[3]]*s};
rm = RotationMatrix[2 ArcCos[First@q], Rest@q];

Show[{ParametricPlot3D[vel* u, {u, -200, 200},PlotRange->{{-5,5},{-5,5},{-5,5}}],Graphics3D[{
  GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[], rm]}]},Axes->True]
```

[image]

This is the exact same misalignment I see in my program. Am I missing some concept for how to align these two vectors? Is it not as simple as making sure the up-axis is projected onto the velocity vector? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think there are some places you wrote $\mathbf v$ when you meant $\hat{\mathbf z}$. If I'm interpreting correctly, I think what you're missing is that you have to normalize $\mathbf a$. If you don't, then $||\mathbf a|| = \sin\theta$ and your rotation is by a really weird angle $\theta'$ where $$\cos\theta'/2 = \frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta + (\sin\theta\sin\theta/2)^2}},\quad\sin\theta'/2 = \frac{\sin\theta\sin\theta/2}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+(\sin\theta\sin\theta/2)^2}}.$$

Comment: Also, "[projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))" is not the correct word to use here, you should just say you want to rotate the $z$-axis to be parallel to $\mathbf v$.

Comment: You might also get a scaling effect if you used $\mathbf q\mathbf x\bar{\mathbf q}$ to perform the rotation, since more properly it should be $\mathbf q\mathbf x\mathbf q^{-1}$ and it just happens that the conjugate and inverse coincide for unit quaternions.